# Watson speech to text returns strange error regarding file size

Tags: curl, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Just started to play with Watson's Voice API.  Trying to use their demo file audio-file.flac.  You'd have to take my word for it that I'm posting the curl command from the directory where it resides, and that according to the ls-l command the file size is  285928 bytes.

This is my post

```
curl -X POST -u xxxxxxxxxx-:yyyyyyyy --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary "audio-file.flac" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"
```

and I get back

> {    "code_description": "Bad Request",    "code": 400,    "error":
>   "Stream was 15 bytes but needs to be at least 100 bytes." }

It's the stream size that makes wonder.  I have a great internet connection, and no matter how many times I try it comes back as 15.  If I change the filename to an incorrect name it reports back as 0.  So where is this 15 coming from?

Anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The issue is here:

```
--data-binary "audio-file.flac"
```

You are telling the command line to send the 15 bytes of your filename as the content of your message. That's why it is failing.

Prepend the filename with an `@` sign. Example:

```
--data-binary @audio-file.flac
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I've tried every form of appending the @  Before quotes, after quotes, and without quotes.  All returns say that 0 bytes were read.

Comment: @O'Doherty which means it's not finding my file.  I can only swear that I am in the directory where the file exists,  So maybe I have the formatting of the command wrong?

Comment: Do 'curl --help' to find the command. I tested on OSX and it works. You can change your file name to see the error change.

Comment: @O'Doherty Thinking maybe I have to look at apache and UFW ports on server

Comment: I used the output option and got the following result.  Am I somehow being denied permission on the Watson side?


**  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file output: Permission denied
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 128)**

Comment: `xxxxxxxxxx-:yyyyyyyy` should not have a `-` sign in it. Otherwise check your service credentials and end point URL.

Comment: that was just me deleting my real username and password.

Comment: @siminO'doherty It's the rights of the directory.  I tried it as "su" and it worked.  Can I ask what the permissions to set the directory to?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Simon O'Doherty response my first problem was that i didn't set the `@` but after fixing that i got the message:

"Stream was 0 bytes but needs to be at least 100 bytes."

And after some research i notice that my error was that i was using `\` instead of `/` so i change that and it worked.

My final route was something like:

```
--data-binary @C:/Users/KARIQUE/Desktop/example.mp3
```

Pd: my OS is windows